# Why does anyone think "alias rm='rm -i'" is a good idea?

Tags: bash, alias, sh, rm

I have used a number of systems where there is a default alias for `rm` to `rm -i`.  I have to assume that this is to try to have users check what they are deleting, but in practice I have only seen this train users to habitually use `rm -rf`, which is incredibly counterproductive.  Not only does it increase required effort and train users to use a more dangerous command, but it also means that a number of features of rm (warning the user on read-only and missing files) are effectively removed.  I understand specific use-cases where `rm -i` would be appropriate, but it seems like a terrible idea for a global alias.

So I repeat my question: Why would anyone think this is a good idea?

Comment: you can unalias a cmd by adding a \ to it, e.g `\rm` in which case the alias will not be expanded.

Comment: @FredrikPihl That is an immensely useful thing to know, thanks.

Comment: You can also simply `unalias rm` in your own local setup files.

Answer (score 4):

`rm -rf` is such a legendarily dangerous command that any shell user should already know to avoid it, regardless of what aliases they have set up. Meanwhile, `alias rm = rm -i` has always seemed to me an obvious and necessary safeguard, given that `rm` is irreversible, unlike sending a file to the trash.

Comment: I would agree, and it makes me cringe whenever I see someone type in `rm -rf folderIjustmade/`.. but none the less people use it habitually after being on a system like that, so I was curious why that is the default.

Comment: `rm` is certainly not irreversible.  `ln foo bar; rm bar; ln foo bar;` The 3rd command reverts the 2nd.

Comment: Well that isn't a common use case, at least not for me.